# How to create cross validation field with vee-validate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I'm trying to use vee-validate to validate 3 fields(text fields) based on a selection of other field(select), but i can't seem to figure how can i do this.

Basically, i have a select box with 5 values, if selected value is equal to 1 or 2, the other 3 fields in the form are required.

Here's an example

[image: vee-validate]
If I select "Ausente" (value 1) or "A desenvolver" (value 2), the other 3 fields are required.

Here's the code that i came up with

```
<v-col cols="2">
    <validation-provider
        rules="required"
        v-slot="{ errors }"
        name="skillLevel"
    >  <!-- If this select has value of 1 or 2 -->
        <v-select
            v-model="answers[n-1][index].skillLevel"
            outlined
            :error-messages="errors"
            :items="selectLevels"
            label="Selecione"
            item-text="level"
            item-value="value"
        ></v-select>
    </validation-provider>
</v-col>

<!-- These 3 fields must be required -->
<v-col cols="2">
    <validation-provider
        name="feedback"
        rules="required||isRequiredWith:@skillLevel"
    >
        <v-textarea v-model="answers[n-1][index].feedBack" outlined rows="3"></v-textarea>
    </validation-provider>
</v-col>

<v-col cols="2">
    <validation-provider name="selfAppraisal" rules="required">
        <v-textarea
            v-model="answers[n-1][index].selfAppraisal"
            outlined
            rows="3"
        ></v-textarea>
    </validation-provider>
</v-col>

<v-col cols="3">
    <validation-provider name="feedforward" rules="required">
        <v-textarea v-model="answers[n-1][index].feedForward" outlined rows="3"></v-textarea>
    </validation-provider>
</v-col>
```

Here's my js

```
import { required} from "vee-validate/dist/rules";
import {
  extend,
  ValidationObserver,
  ValidationProvider,
  setInteractionMode
} from "vee-validate";

setInteractionMode("eager");

extend("required", {
  ...required,
  message: "Campo não pode ficar em branco"
});

extend("isRequiredWith", {
  params: ["target"],
  validate(value, { target }) {
    if (target === 1 || target === 2) {
      console.log(target);
      //Problem is here, i'm messing up the value/target, don't what i need to check
      console.log("cannot be empty");
    }
  },
  message: "Required"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going wrong, it seems like your code should basically work.  I gave it a try though and it never bothers to run the `isRequiredWith` validation when the target value changes.  So here's an alternative way that doesn't require making your own rule:

```
<validation-provider
    name="feedback"
    :rules="{required:(answers[n-1][index].skillLevel == 1 || answers[n-1][index].skillLevel == 2)}"
>
    <v-textarea v-model="answers[n-1][index].feedBack" outlined rows="3"></v-textarea>
</validation-provider>
```

It's not pretty but it works.  See a simplified example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-30-cross-field-validation-gpkj9

Comment: Hello Ryley, thanks for the response. I'm using vee-validate version 3.2.5.
Tried that way you showed, but still can't make it validate. The if statement is right, because if I put a log there... it shows on the console. but the return statement isn't returning anything

Comment: Yeah, OK... I think if it's not required it just doesn't trigger the rule at all... So let me revise my answer

Comment: Ryley, I tried your new answer, and it works. At first it didn't worked, but I noticed that i forgot to add the errors var to show the errors. So thanks for your help